# Checkbox not remaining checked when validations triggered on other fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a rails form in which i have a few text fields like first name, last name and a terms and conditions checkbox, i have few validations as well like first name cannot be blank.

The issue i am facing is when i check the terms and conditions checkbox and there are validations triggered on other fields, the checkbox does not remain checked.

While, the text values that I enter in first name or last name remain set when validations are triggered.

here is my form code

```
<%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "first name", placeholder: 'First Name'%>
<%= f.text_field :last_name, autofocus: false, autocomplete: "last name", placeholder: 'Last Name'%>
<%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: false, autocomplete: "email", placeholder: 'Email'%>
<%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", placeholder: 'Password' %>
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", placeholder: 'Password Confirmation' %>
<%= f.check_box :terms_and_conditions %>
```

my question is while the other forms fields persist the data when there are validations triggered the checkbox does not do that, is that the expected behaviour or is there something I am doing wrong.

**How do also persist the checkbox data and show it checked if its checked when there is error on other fields.**

Thanks.

Comment: Show your controller and model, please. Is there a `terms_and_conditions` getter and setter on the model and are you whitelisting this param in the controller?

Comment: the controller is devise registration controller, the model or controller does not have any specific code for the terms_and_conditions column

Comment: Hi @fphilipe, you were right, it was a silly mistake i made where i did not whitelist the terms_and_conditions column in my registrations controller and it started to work as expected after that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a silly mistake on my part, I had to not added the checkbox column in the permitted list of columns, once i added that, it fixed the issue.

Thanks.